# How to put a date check in Django Templates

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to hide some data after the 10th day of every month. How can I implement this check?

I dont want to make any function in the views . 
And there should be something publicly used over the web site in Templates .

Comment: this question is the same earlier with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402914/how-to-put-a-date-check-in-django-templates. Same person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% if date.day <= 10 %}
    //show data
{% else %}
    //no data
{% endif %}
```

Comment: for today date can we set a specific one ? I mean  

{% if date.day > (Date ==10) %}
    //show data
{% else %}
    //no data
{% endif %}

Comment: `{% if date.day <= 10 %}`

Comment: Do we need to import date in views for this .. beacuse it shows nothing in the template for now.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in template

```
{% if your_date.day < 10 %}
    {# show the data #}
{% else %}
    {# hide data #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `after the 10th day`, <= ?

Answer (score 1):

This is literally the exact same question as this one:
[get particular date in django template Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401591/get-particular-date-in-django-template-django)

I answered completely in that one.

Comment: You can vote to close the question as a duplicate by hitting the 'Close' button below the tags in the original question